# How to notify user of session expiration

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm building a CMS using Codeigniter and I'm using Ion Auth for authentication.

While doing some testing on a post creation page (think Wordpress add new post), I noticed that some Ajax stuff would fail if a user's session expired. Now I will likely add something to return a message in the Ajax controller, but I'd like to display a message before they take any actions that their login session is going to/has expired.

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: I do it by getting an ajax response as text, parseing it as JSON (as the data returned is JSON) and if it failed to parse then we were possibly redirected to the login page (html - non JSON). (but thats on an existing system so had to do a work around)

Comment: You could look at the expiration date/time of the cookie, unless the cookie was set httponly.  Even if it isn't, that's not sure to be the gospel expiration time of the session as there's also a server expiration time after which the session data is GC'd.  You could poll the server with AJAx repeatedly to see if the session is still valid, but that's a lot of extra work and traffic for little material gain.  Your best bet is just making your AJAX stuff that depends on the session fail gracefully if the session expires.  That or use HTTP auth instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could add $_SESSION['CREATEDTIME'] and store datetime() in it. Compare it through AJAX and add a label or similar to notify user when the session is going to expire.